# How do I use JS modules on Zapier for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, zapier

Can someone with good JavaScript and Zapier knowledge understand how to create a script to connect to Firebase and create a new user… according to Firebase documentation for JavaScript the code below that I have researched and put together is correct. However when I try to test it on a zap i get this error - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  MY DATA CENSORED
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "TESTUSERNAME", "TESTPASSWORD")
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know zapier, but the evident problem has nothing to do with firebase or any other part of your code besides the import. If this were my question, I'd rewrite it to focus on "how do i use js modules on zapier?" My MRE would be to import something and log it.

Comment: The problem with Zapier its just a text box you copy code in. There are no extra features to import